# Android MediaPlayer streaming MP3 over POST

Tags: android, http, post, media-player, audio-streaming

I've got a question related to the Android MediaPlayer. Can it stream content through HTTP POST method , or do I have to write my own implementation? If so, what SDK do I have to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, the URL you want to supply will return some sort of media? This trick worked for me with a *3gp file*. Assuming the HTTP POST request parameters will be feed through the URL.

```
URL url = new URL("insert-url-path-here");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.connect();
con.getContent(); //This is needed or setDataSource will throw IOException
m_mediaPlayer.setDataSource(con.getURL().toString());
m_mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start(); //Dont forget to setOnPreparedListener
}
```

Let me know how it went.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I'm trying to reach an HTTP Auth protected mp3 stream - i.e. icecast server....  Any idea on how to do that?